# Add Custom Image via a Subclass to Annotation and Add a Segue

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, segue

I would like to add a custom image for a callout annotation via a subclass (previous questions did not include using a subclass)

Here is my code thus far:

**Subclass named "Capital.swift"**

```
import MapKit
import UIKit

class Capital: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    var title: String?
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var info: String

    // here we would add the custom image

    init(title: String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, info: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.coordinate = coordinate
        self.info = info

     // add additional lines as needed

    }
}
```

**Here is my code for the ViewController.swift**

```
import MapKit
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let london = Capital(title: "London", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.507222, longitude: -0.1275), info: "Home to the 2012 Summer Olympics.")
        let oslo = Capital(title: "Oslo", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 59.95, longitude: 10.75), info: "Founded over a thousand years ago.")
        let paris = Capital(title: "Paris", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 48.8567, longitude: 2.3508), info: "Often called the City of Light.")
        let rome = Capital(title: "Rome", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 41.9, longitude: 12.5), info: "Has a whole country inside it.")
        let washington = Capital(title: "Washington DC", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 38.895111, longitude: -77.036667), info: "Named after George himself.")

        mapView.addAnnotations([london, oslo, paris, rome, washington])
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

        let identifier = "Capital"
        if annotation is Capital {
            if let annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier) {
                annotationView.annotation = annotation
                return annotationView
            } else {
                let annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation:annotation, reuseIdentifier:identifier)
                annotationView.isEnabled = true
                annotationView.canShowCallout = true

                let btn = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
                annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = btn
            return annotationView
         }
       }
        return nil
    }
```

**Here we add the custom image to the annotationView**

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
        let capital = view.annotation as! Capital
        let placeName = capital.title
        let placeInfo = capital.info

        // Add custom image


    // Add Segue

 performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue1", sender: (capital.title, capital.coordinate, capital.info))

        }
    }
```

Thanks